# Integrating expressions with several terms and delta functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

So I want to integrate an expression that looks something like this:

```
Integrate[f[x]+DiracDelta[x-y]g[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

With some more terms added with delta functions after g[x]. Even after expanding and simplifying Mathematica won't break up the expression and evaluate the delta function, it just leaves it in exactly the form I have above. How do I make Mathematica evaluate the integral term by term?

Cheers :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to see if you can use [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html) for this:

```
Distribute@
 Integrate[f[x] + DiracDelta[x - y] g[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> [image: distribute]

Unlike `Map`, `Distribute` is especially (though not exclusively) intended for use with *sums*.

Comment: Perfect. My only problem with that is some of my terms should actually be integrated over a different dummy variable. Apart from that it looks great.

Comment: Actually, nevermind - you're a life saver :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach, admittedly not elegant, is

```
Map[Integrate[#, {x, -∞, ∞}] &, f[x] + DiracDelta[x - y] g[x]]
(* ConditionalExpression[g[y] + Integrate[f[x], {x, -∞, ∞}], Element[y, Reals]] *)
```

Incidentally, the code in the Question can be rewritten as

```
Integrate[#, {x, -∞, ∞}] & @ (f[x] + DiracDelta[x - y] g[x])
```

and the code at the beginning of this Answer as

```
Integrate[#, {x, -∞, ∞}] & /@ (f[x] + DiracDelta[x - y] g[x])
```

From this perspective the change needed to integrate `DiracDelta` is small.

**Addendum**

In response to the OP's Comment below, if the integral in the Question is designated `int` (for instance), then

```
int = Integrate[f[x]+DiracDelta[x-y]g[x],{x,-∞, ∞}];
Integrate[#, {x, -∞, ∞}] & /@ int[[1]]
```

produces the desired result without copying the integrand.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, the only problem is that my expression is actually about 20 terms long, none of the terms are the same and 18 have delta functions. So a simple replacement rule like that will only work if I actually write in all 20 terms myself, in which case I might as well not bother.

Comment: @SpamuelNeedbeef  Does the addendum address your issue?

Comment: It does, but some of my terms in the integral are actually over different dummy variables - an unfortunately unavoidable annoyance.

Comment: All sorted. Thanks folks!